# No thread-bound request found with Spring when Kafka receive a message

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I 'm getting this error from my service

```
jvm org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl {"@trace_info":"[availability-psql,eba16d49e23479cc,675789f41e0dda5b,eba16d49e23479cc,false]", "@message": "HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.infoUser': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.]
```

This is because of I have a bean of scope @ScopeRequest. This problem show up when a new message from kafka is received and I try to update my data base with spring data. If I remove my @Transactional I don't have any problem to save the data.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaMastersConfig.topics}", containerFactory = "mastersContainerFactory")
  @Transactional
  @Authorized
  public void consumeWrapperMasterChangeEvent(@Payload String payload,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,  @Nullable @Header(AUTHORIZATION) String authorization) throws IOException {
    try {
    log.info("Received change event in masters: '{}'", payload);

    RequestAttributes context = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);

    changeProcessorFactory.getEntityChangeProcessor(getEntityFromTopic(topic)).processChange(payload);

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
     log.error("Error proccesing message {} ", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
    }


  }
```

And here is the bean:

```
@RequestScope
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class InfoUser {

  private DecodedJWT jwt;

  public String getCurrentUser() {
    if (jwt == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return jwt.getSubject();
  }

  public String getAuthorizationBearer() {
    if (jwt == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return jwt.getToken();
  }
}
```

And this class:

```
public class CustomRequestScopeAttr implements RequestAttributes {

  private Map<String, Object> requestAttributeMap = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public Object getAttribute(String name, int scope) {
    if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
      return this.requestAttributeMap.get(name);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void setAttribute(String name, Object value, int scope) {
    if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
      this.requestAttributeMap.put(name, value);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void removeAttribute(String name, int scope) {
    if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
      this.requestAttributeMap.remove(name);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String[] getAttributeNames(int scope) {
    if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
      return this.requestAttributeMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    }
    return new String[0];
  }

  @Override
  public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback, int scope) {
    // Not Supported
  }

  @Override
  public Object resolveReference(String key) {
    // Not supported
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getSessionId() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getSessionMutex() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And futhermore I have an aspect class to save the authorization token:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthorizationAspect {

  private final AuthorizationDecoder authorizationDecoder;

  private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Around("@annotation(Authorized)")
  public Object setInfoUser(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    try {
      String[] parameterNames = ((CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getParameterNames();
      Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
      Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (null != args[i]) {
          arguments.put(parameterNames[i], args[i]);
        }
      }
      Object authorization = arguments.get("authorization");
      RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new CustomRequestScopeAttr());

      InfoUser infoUser = applicationContext.getBean(InfoUser.class);
      infoUser.setJwt(authorizationDecoder.decodeToken((String) authorization));

      return joinPoint.proceed();

    } finally {
      RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
    }

  }
```

And the last class is trying to save de info:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RoomChangeMaster implements ChangeMaster<Room> {

  private final TimetableRepository timetableRepository;

  private final AvailabilityRepository availabilityRepository;

  @Override
  public void processChange(Room entity, ActionEnum action) {

    if (action == ActionEnum.updated) {

      List<Timetable> timetables = (List<Timetable>) timetableRepository.findByRoomId(entity.getId());
      Room room = timetables.get(0).getRoom();
      room.setDescription(entity.getDescription());
      room.setCode(entity.getCode());
      timetables.forEach(timetable -> {
        timetable.setRoom(room);
        timetableRepository.save(timetable);
      });

      availabilityRepository
          .updateAvailabilityRoomByRoomId(room, entity.getId());

    } else {

      throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + action);

    }
  }
}
```

I have spent a lot of time finding out the problem, but so far, I was not able to know the problem. Any idea will be appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`RequestContextHolder` is for Spring-MVC - it is for a Web request only and is populated with information from an HTTP request.

```
/**
 * Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound
 * {@link RequestAttributes} object. The request will be inherited
 * by any child threads spawned by the current thread if the
 * {@code inheritable} flag is set to {@code true}.
 *
...
```

There is no equivalent for listener containers (of any type) because there is no "incoming request".

Looks like your hibernate code is tightly tied to the web.

If you are trying to reuse existing code you need to decouple it and use some other technique to pass information between the layers (e.g. a custom equivalent of `RequestContextHolder`).

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to investigate other technique, because currently I have no idea how can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved it changing the hiberante method save by saveAndFlush